# How do I measure the performance of remote docker container in hyperledger caliper?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

i am currently utilizing Hyperledger Caliper to measure the performance of each docker containers. I am currently using two servers and the former has 2 peers and 2 orderers and the other one has 2 peers and 1 orderer. At the former server side, I can measure the local containers' performance (2 peers and 2 orderers) but I cannot measure the performance of the other one's performance.

```
monitors:
  resource:
  - module: docker
    options:
      interval: 5
      containers:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - orderer.example.com
      - orderer2.example.com
      - http://10.0.0.252:9051/peer0.org2.example.com
```

peer0.org2.example.com exists at the latter server.
But errors arises like

**could not start monitors: typererror: cannot read properties of undefined {hasOwnproperty}**

If I just type just like below

```
monitors:
  resource:
  - module: docker
    options:
      interval: 5
      containers:
      - all
```

I can see the loal containers' performance. But I really wish to measure the remote containers' performance.
what should I do now?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in caliper 0.5, you can raise an issue here https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper but if you need it fixed sooner then I would recommend submitting a PR to fix the issue. It looks like this line is the issue https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper/blob/d4c593923cca5fef4004d44a4d43fe3cbe8c04b4/packages/caliper-core/lib/manager/monitors/monitor-docker.js#L75

Comment: @david_k thank you, you were right. Caliper has a wrong code line there. Thank you a lot!